# Option clash for package xcolor compiling

Tags: color

What does these error mean please?

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \usepackage
```

This is preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage
\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

%% Použité kódování znaků: obvykle latin2, cp1250 nebo utf8:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%% Další užitečné balíčky (jsou součástí běžných distribucí LaTeXu)
\usepackage{amsmath}        % rozšíření pro sazbu matematiky
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % matematické fonty
\usepackage{amsthm}         % sazba vět, definic apod.
\usepackage{bbding}         % balíček s nejrůznějšími symboly
                % (čtverečky, hvězdičky, tužtičky, nůžtičky, ...)
\usepackage{bm}             % tučné symboly (příkaz \bm)
\usepackage{graphicx}       % vkládání obrázků
\usepackage{fancyvrb}       % vylepšené prostředí pro strojové písmo
\usepackage{indentfirst}    % zavede odsazení 1. odstavce kapitoly
\usepackage{natbib}         % zajištuje možnost odkazovat na literaturu
                % stylem AUTOR (ROK), resp. AUTOR [ČÍSLO]
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % zajistí přidání seznamu literatury,
                            % obrázků a tabulek do obsahu
\usepackage{icomma}         % inteligetní čárka v matematickém módu
\usepackage{dcolumn}        % lepší zarovnání sloupců v tabulkách
\usepackage{booktabs}       % lepší vodorovné linky v tabulkách
\usepackage{paralist}       % lepší enumerate a itemize
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}  % barevná sazba
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{icomma,dcolumn,booktabs}


\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
```

I tried

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw}{xcolor}
```

but it didn't help.

Error is on this line

```
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just put the `\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor} ` first. I also get a `No color profile found to use for RGB screen colors..` because of `\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}` but perhaps this is not a problem for you? Btw, rather than just posting your preamble, it is better to post a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that people can compile to see your problem.

Comment: `\PassOptionsToPackage` should appear very soon after `\documentclass`, in order to give the packages a chance to get aware of the provided options.

Comment: Off-topic: The manual `\textheight` etc. setting right after `\documentclass` is weird. Please use `\usepackage{geometry}` with appropiate options for such layout changes

Comment: Anyway, you don't need the `[usenames]` option nowadays: it is the default.

Comment: amsmath, amssymb, bm, icomma, dcolumn, booktabs, lmodern and textcomp packages is also loaded twice in your example. And you should consider providing `pdfx` with a metadata file and set either `\setRGBcolorprofile` or `\setCMYKcolorprofile`  as per the documentation.

Comment: It works on computer, but it doesn't work on notebook. There is wasn't update of MiKTeX, so I want to reinstall it, however it wasn't possible, so I deleted the folder of MiKTeX and install it again. Now I have twice MiKTeX and it doesn't work at all. No of them is possible to reinstall. Should I download TeXLive?